# Outlook Add-In that is compatible with both Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have a Outlook Add-In that is working in Outlook 2007, but it is not working in Outlook 2010.

Basically, the Add-in has a button in the toolbar, and a Custom Property Page, and when the button is clicked All the Information related to that Email is captured.

But in Outlook 2010, that button itself is not coming up, neither is the Custom Property page, is it possible to make that Add-in working ??

Thanks,
Shrenik

Answer (score 1):

How do you add the button in Outlook 2007?

If you use the old CommandBars in Outlook 2010 or 2013, your button will be on the Addins Ribbon.